# If condition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file which is getting embedded into the master xml file, below is the xml file format

```
<TEST_RESULT>
<MODULE_NAME>CREATE-SETVC-NUM</MODULE_NAME>
<CLASS_NAME>Create</CLASS_NAME>
<NUMBER_OF_PASSED>4</NUMBER_OF_PASSED>
<NUMBER_OF_FAILED>4</NUMBER_OF_FAILED>
<TOTAL_COUNT>8</TOTAL_COUNT>
<CLASS_NAME1>SetVC</CLASS_NAME1>
<NUMBER_OF_PASSED1>4</NUMBER_OF_PASSED1>
<NUMBER_OF_FAILED1>4</NUMBER_OF_FAILED1>
<TOTAL_COUNT1>8</TOTAL_COUNT1>
</TEST_RESULT>
```

Now my XSLT file i need to check an condition that when nodes `<CLASS_NAME>` and `<CLASS_NAME1>` both nodes exists need to perform some operation, now i tried this below condition

```
    <xsl:when test="CLASS_NAME and CLASS_NAME1">
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="MODULE_NAME"/></b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="CLASS_NAME"/></b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER_OF_PASSED"/></b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER_OF_FAILED"/></b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="TOTAL_COUNT"/></b></font></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="CLASS_NAME1"/></b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER_OF_PASSED1"/></b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER_OF_FAILED1"/></b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor = "#E0FFFF"><font face = "courier"><b><xsl:value-of select="TOTAL_COUNT1"/></b></font></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:when>
```

but this condition is failing any idea why its failing?

Answer (score 3):

needs to be either:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="CLASS_NAME and CLASS_NAME1">
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

or:

```
<xsl:if test="CLASS_NAME and CLASS_NAME1">
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Condition check are of two types in XSLT 1.0

1. xsl If condition to match a template,

   `<xsl:if test="expr">`

   `<!-- your code -->`

   `</xsl:if>`
2. element is used in conjunction with  and  to express multiple conditional tests.

   ```
     `<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="expr">
        <!-- your code -->
       </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- your code -->
      </xsl:otherwise>
   ```

   `

,

**Reference:**

[w3schools.com/xsl/]
[zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XSLT_1.html]

to learn xslt zvon is very good site for newbies :)